# Keep getting this exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0) and height (0) cannot be <= 0

Tags: java, image

I want to display an icon, that's why I've created a method, but when I call the method the image doesn't want to appear. I have tried to add a button to check whether the method works or not. I don't know whether the method is working properly or not though. The method should  work, the problem is though that the image won't show up.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import javax.swing.*;`


public final class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {
Connection conn=null;
ResultSet rs=null;
PreparedStatement ps=null;


public Login() {
      image3();
      initComponents();
      conn = javaconnect.ConnectDB();
      DateNow();
      txt_username.requestFocus();
      }

public final void image3(){
try{
     String sql= "SELECT * from Picture";   
     ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
     rs=ps.executeQuery();
     if (rs.next()){

     byte[] imagedata = rs.getBytes("Background");
     format = new ImageIcon(imagedata);

     Image img = format.getImage();
     ImageIcon img2 = new    ImageIcon(ScaledImage(img,showimage.getWidth(),showimage.getHeight()));
     showimage.setIcon(img2);


      rs.close();
      ps.close();      
     }
 }
        catch(Exception e){}

 finally {

        try{
           rs.close();
            ps.close();
            //conn close
            }

        catch(Exception e){}

     }
    }

public Image ScaledImage(Image img, int w, int h){
BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage (w,h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2 = resizedImage.createGraphics();
g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
g2.drawImage(img, 0,0,w,h,null);
g2.dispose();


return resizedImage;
}
```

## Exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at Login.image3(Login.java:43)
at Login.<init>(Login.java:19)
at Login$2.run(Login.java:327)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

### Getting new Exception after change the image(); below

`conn=javaconnect.ConnectDB()`

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Width (0) and height (0) cannot be <= 0`

Comment: Yes it doesn't function, why?

Comment: Any exception? What's returned from the database?

Comment: i have no idea when i try to use action performed from button it is working...

Comment: no exception and the image wont show

Comment: Why are you swallowing the Exception ? `catch(Exception e){}`

Comment: Maybe it throws an exception but you have ignored it. Please add `e.printStackTrace` or an alert and come back here with the message (if any)

Comment: i have place the print stack and it give me null pointer exception any idea why..?

Comment: I think you have a `}` error, is it from copy/paste?

Comment: after doing some research i think it is because the image does not fully loaded thats why it throws that exception can someone help me with this

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new class called Machine

```
class Machine {
private String name;
private int code;

public Machine() {
    this("Arnie", 0);

    System.out.println("Constructor running!");
}

public Machine(String name) {
    this(name, 0);

    System.out.println("Second constructor running");

}

public Machine(String name, int code) {

    System.out.println("Third constructor running");
    this.name = name;
    this.code = code;
}
```

}

and used it in the main class App

```
public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Machine machine1 = new Machine();

    Machine machine2 = new Machine("Bertie");

    Machine machine3 = new Machine("Chalky", 7);
}
```

}

So the constructor has the name of the class and you can say that it's a special method that runs automatically when you are using any object of that class .

at the first constructor I've used two parameters String and Integer , when you call an object and pass these parameters to it , will automatically run the constructor that have those parameters..

Got It ?

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to make a constructor for your class to start automatically when you call it with the parameters you want ... I may not understand

Comment: can u give an example ??

Comment: I've Improved my answer check it :)